# Русские названия полей базы данных в админке

Tags: python, django

Вопрос банально простой, но что-то не разобрался... Как сделать, что бы в админке отображались русские названия для полей базы данных? Что нужно прописывать в models.py?

Comment: Не самая лучшая идея делать русские имена таблицам.

Comment: Вы не поняли... Не таблицы называть русскими именами, а что бы названия ПОЛЕЙ в АДМИНКЕ были на русском.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
user = models.ForeignKey( User, verbose_name=u"Пользователь" )
```

Comment: Большущее спасибо, то, что надо :) Может подскажете, как указать и названия таблиц? :)

Comment: Тут уже поизвращаться надо - писать свой тэг, заменять им буржуйские слова.

Comment: Ладно, черти с ними, с этими таблицами... Еще раз спасибо :)

Answer (score 3):

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(u'Название', max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'tag_table'
        verbose_name = u'Тэг'
        verbose_name_plural = u'Тэги'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

При этом ни что вам не заменит документацию. [Тут смотреть](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/options/)

Ну и стандартно вначале файла с моделями, что бы не было проблем:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: db_table меняет название таблицы для базы данных, это вообще ни к чему... app_label меняет название прилдожения, к которому принадлежит таблица, однако если использовать русские символы - в админке начинаются проблемы... Название приложения заносится в адресную строку, и получается конфликт :(

Comment: Я лишь ответил, см. выше: Большущее спасибо, то, что надо :) Может подскажете, как указать и названия таблиц? :)

Comment: Так вы же сами это указали в своем ответе, строчка "db_table = 'tag_table'" :)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

После чего в админке будет отображаться то, что вернёт метод `__unicode__`

Comment: Это не то, данный метод подходит только для одного поля, а если у меня их 10? Да и на странице редактирования записи все равно все поля называются по-английски. Т.е. я хочу, что бы поле name = models.CharField(max_length=50) отображалось не как "name", а как "Название", например. И так для каждого поля.

Comment: Ты хочешь сделать что - то типа многоязычной программы? )
ЧТобы можно было подставлять любые слова под определённый столбец? )

name=название=назва...? )

Comment: Ну не многоязыковой... А только приятной для взгляда русского человека :) Согласитесь, что гораздо приятнее работать в админке, где понятно, какое поле для чего, а не одни названия вроде "name", "title" и прочего...

Answer (score 0):

На всякий случай на будущее, если в качестве поля используется функция то ей тоже можно менять название

```
class SomeModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['__unicode__', 'admin_image_preview']

    def admin_image_preview(self, obj):
        if obj.image:
            thumbnail = get_thumbnail(obj.image, '70')
            return '<a href="%s" target="blank"><image src="%s"/></a>' % (obj.image.url, thumbnail.url)
        return ''
    admin_image_preview.short_description = u'превью'
    admin_image_preview.allow_tags = True
```

[image]